# "Главная" попала в хлебные крошки поиска google

Tags: wordpress, seo, schema.org, breadcrumbs

Сайт еще в стадии разработки, в индекс не отправлял, но гугл сам скушал, как в яндексе отображаться будет - не знаю. Вообщем суть вопроса: в гугл в хлебные крошки попало слово "Главная" (смотрите скриншот). Нужно убрать, не соображу что сделано не так))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно сам код:

```html
<div class="breadcrumb" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
<span class="breadcrumb-item" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
<a href="http://site.ru/" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemprop="item">
<span itemprop="name">Главная</span></a><meta itemprop="position" content="1"></span> 
<span class="breadcrumb-separator">»</span> 
<span class="breadcrumb-item" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
<a href="http://site.ru/category-name/" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemprop="item">
<span itemprop="name">Название категории</span></a><meta itemprop="position" content="2"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> в гугл в хлебные крошки

Речь о хлебных крошках в сниппете? В таком случае, вероятно, дело во внутренних ссылках. 
Например, у вас ссылки на главную страницу из меню/логотипа имеют вид "site.ru", а в разметке хлебных крошек указано "site.ru/" - вот уже и формально другая вложенность. Таким образом гугл, анализируя сайт видит, что есть ссылки на страницу site.ru (безанкорные), на страницу site.ru/ (с анкором "Главная") и их много. Ну и ссылки на страницы категорий, но их намного меньше. Вот в соответствии со статистикой внутренних ссылок и формируются хлебные крошки.

**Что делать:**

1. Разобраться со внутренними ссылками в первую очередь (в т.ч. всевозможные карты сайта и прочие списки ссылок).
2. Посмотреть в SearchConsole - там раньше была информация насчет внутренней перелинковки и статистика по анкорам.